# Share a downloaded video path from react native app to tiktok

Tags: react-native, share, tiktok, react-native-share

I am downloading video from react native app in android and saving it to cache. Now i want to open tiktok from my react native app and share the downloaded video that is in cache to tiktok.
Is there any way to perform this functionality on react-native Android and IOS??